# Salesforce - Apex Class/Trigger to not allow 3 consecutive characters

Tags: java, regex, triggers, salesforce, apex

I have created a trigger wherein it will not allow to save a record if the specific field populated with a 3 consecutive characters. But it is not working. Anyone here who has an idea on how to implement this?

See below the triggerhandler:

```
public class TaskHandlerController {

public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Task> TaskList){

Set<String> taskID = new Set<String>();

for(Task a: TaskList){
    taskID.add(a.Id);
}

List<Task> updatePurpose = [SELECT Id, Purpose__c, Subject,Description FROM Task WHERE Id IN : taskID];

Map<String,Task> CommentMap = new Map<String,Task>();

for(Task a : updatePurpose){
    if(a.Description == 'aaa'){
        CommentMap.put(a.Description,a);

    }
}

for(Task a: TaskList){
    if(a.Description == 'aaa'){
        a.addError('Your custom error message');
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Try `if(Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{2}").matcher(a.Description).find()) { a.addError('Your custom error message'); }`

Comment: Hi Wiktor. It works now. Thank you :)